# Average entries with duplicate first element in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array that looks like this

```
  arr = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3]])
```

and I would like to take the average of the 'entries' that have the same first element, i.e. my output should be

```
  [ [0, avg(1,2)] , [1, avg(3, 3, 4)], [2, 3] ]
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a NumPythonic solution using [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) for a generic case when the first column is not always sorted -

```
unqa,ID,counts = np.unique(arr[:,0],return_inverse=True,return_counts=True)
out = np.column_stack(( unqa , np.bincount(ID,arr[:,1])/counts ))
```

Sample run -

```
In [4]: arr
Out[4]: 
array([[5, 1],
       [5, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 3],
       [5, 4],
       [2, 3]])

In [5]: unqa,ID,counts = np.unique(arr[:,0],return_inverse=True,return_counts=True)
   ...: out = np.column_stack(( unqa , np.bincount(ID,arr[:,1])/counts ))
   ...: 

In [6]: out
Out[6]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  3.        ],
       [ 2.        ,  3.        ],
       [ 5.        ,  2.33333333]])
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to pandas (recommended for this type of manipulation), this works:

```
arr = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3]])
pd.DataFrame(arr).groupby(0).mean()

          1
0
0  1.500000
1  3.333333
2  3.000000
```

If you like an numpy array back again, just use the `values` attribute:

```
pd.DataFrame(arr).groupby(0).mean().values
>>> array([[ 1.5       ],
...        [ 3.33333333],
...        [ 3.        ]])
```

Which of course loses the indices. But, depending on your need, it may be more useful to manipulate the resulting dataframe, instead of using a (shortened) 2D numpy array.

(For clarity:

```
pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

is

```
   0  1
0  0  1
1  0  2
2  1  3
3  1  3
4  1  4
5  2  3
```

hence the use of `0` as the column index in `groupby`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to grouping your items them use `np.mean()` within a list comprehension to get the expected result:

```
>>> for i,j in arr:
...    d.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
... 
>>> d
{0: [1, 2], 1: [3, 3, 4], 2: [3]}
>>> 
>>> [[i,np.mean(j)] for i,j in d.items()]
[[0, 1.5], [1, 3.3333333333333335], [2, 3.0]]
```

Or if you want the data in a rounded mode:

```
>>> [[i,round(np.mean(j),2)] for i,j in d.items()]
[[0, 1.5], [1, 3.33], [2, 3.0]]
```