# Average rows with duplicate first element in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy array like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 4, 5, 6],
 [3, 2, 3, 4]]
```

What I want to do is average the rows of each duplicate first entry. In this example, averaging the second to last column of the first and third rows. The correct output should be:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 2, 3, 4],
 [3, 2, 3, 4]]
```

This answer [Average entries with duplicate first element in 2D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668125/average-entries-with-duplicate-first-element-in-2d-numpy-array) is very much related to what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's a vectorized one with NumPy -

```
def groupby_mean(a):
    # Sort array by groupby column
    b = a[a[:,0].argsort()]

    # Get interval indices for the sorted groupby col
    idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,b[:-1,0]!=b[1:,0],True])

    # Get counts of each group and sum rows based on the groupings & hence averages
    counts = np.diff(idx)
    avg = np.add.reduceat(b[:,1:],idx[:-1],axis=0)/counts.astype(float)[:,None]

    # Finally concatenate for the output in desired format
    return np.c_[b[idx[:-1],0],avg]
```

**Approach #2**

Another vectorized one leveraging `matrix-multiplication` -

```
def groupby_mean_matmul(a):
    unq = np.unique(a[:,0])
    m = a[:,0,None] == unq
    return np.c_[unq, m.T.dot(a[:,1:])/m.sum(0)[:,None].astype(float)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [51]: a
Out[51]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 2, 3, 4]])

In [52]: groupby_mean(a)
Out[52]: 
array([[1., 3., 4., 5.],
       [2., 2., 3., 4.],
       [3., 2., 3., 4.]])
```

Comment: Approach #1 is incredibly fast! Thank you! I wonder why wouldn't NumPy invest in developing groupby functions.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [2, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 4, 5, 6],
     [3, 2, 3, 4]], 
    columns=list('abcd')
    )

df.groupby('a').mean().reset_index().values
# returns:
array([[1, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 2, 3, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Pandas solves the problem but unfortunately I have to use numpy only.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
l = [np.argwhere(i==a[:,0]).ravel() for i in np.unique(a[:,0])]
np.array([a[i].mean(axis=0).tolist() for i in l])

array([[1., 3., 4., 5.],
       [2., 2., 3., 4.],
       [3., 2., 3., 4.]])
```

**Explanation**

In regards to the first list comprehension, [`np.arwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) will return an array with the indices of the rows with a common first element, for every [`unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) element

```
l = [np.argwhere(i==a[:,0]).ravel() for i in np.unique(a[:,0])]
[array([0, 2]), array([1]), array([3])]
```

Now you just need to slice `a` according to each array in `l` and average it with:

```
np.array([a[i].mean(axis=0).tolist() for i in l])

array([[1., 3., 4., 5.],
       [2., 2., 3., 4.],
       [3., 2., 3., 4.]])
```

Comment: Good solution, maybe a little terse on the explanation ;)